# Breakpoint not working in C++ program in Xcode 7

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, xcode7, breakpoints

Here is my very simple program:

```
void func(int a);

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    func(a);  // <-- bp
    return 0;
}

void func(int a) { int another_a = a; }
```

Before I debug, I place a a breakpoint placed on the line indicated with a `// <-- bp`.

---

When I press "run", it stops there (as expected).

Then I press "step in", it goes through `func()` (as expected).

Then I press "continue program execution", it goes back to `main()` and finished the program (again, as expected).

---

Now, I edit the program as such:

```
void func(int* a);

int main()
{
    int b = 0;
    func(&b); // <-- bp
    return 0;
}

void func(int* a) { int* another_a = a; }
```

I run this version.

---

When I press "run", it stops there (as expected).

**Here's the problem:** Then I press "step in", it doesn't go into `func()`, rather it's as if I pressed "step over".

---

Notes:

- The program compiles.
- No errors (warning about the uselessness of
  `another_a`, though).

---

It seems as if my code is legit, so I assume that something is wrong with Xcode.